# Eclipse misunderstands exception-throwing aspect

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, aspectj

In Eclipse + AJDT, I implemented a method annotation to check for authorisation as follows.

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secured {}
```

Aspect:

```
public aspect SecurityCheck {
  pointcut checkSecurity(Secured annotation) : execution(@Secured * *.*(..)) && @annotation(annotation);

  Object around(Secured annotation) throws PermissionException:
    checkSecurity(annotation) {
    ...
    if (...) throw new PermissionException();
    ...
    return proceed(annotation);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Secured
public void someMethod() {}
```

The annotation marks all the methods where the aspect should be applied. Aspect checks authorisation and throws `PermissionException` on failure.

However, as it is a checked exception, `someMethod()` needs to declare it:

```
@Secured
public void someMethod() throws PermissionException {}
```

Eclipse does not like this: there is nothing inside `someMethod()` to throw `PermissionException`, so it complains. I have to do a workaround:

```
@Secured
public void someMethod() throws PermissionException {
  warn();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void warn() throws PermissionException {}
```

This makes Eclipse happy and it works just fine. However, it is quite ugly to call `warn()` every time just to make Eclipse shut up.

What could be done better? Is this a straightforward Eclipse bug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've stumbled upon a bug (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240608) here which didn't get fixed I believe.

Do you need it to be a checked exception?

Comment: I am afraid I need it to be checked. The bug you mention does not seem to be really related to my problem...

Comment: So you're aspect in Eclipse is compiling as is? Your not getting an error that says `can't throw checked exception...`?

Comment: Yes, my aspect is compiling just fine in Eclipse.

Comment: Apologies I can't help my aspects with checked exception don't compile in eclipse the way you've got it.